# How to backup a registry key n value using c#

Tags: c#

Before editing registry value, i want to back-up(save in a textfile or some other option?) a certain portion of key-value.How to do it in C#

Comment: Have you at least tried searching?

Answer (score 2):

[Read the registry key](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sushmita_kumari/RegistryKeys102082006061720AM/RegistryKeys1.aspx) and store the key and value some where. Then write them back if required.